# How can a game publisher legally "pull their game off" of geforce now?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property

I do not know exactly what category this question should be under.
So this is what geforce now basically is:

> GeForce Now lets users access a virtual computer, where they can install their existing games from existing digital distribution platforms, and play them remotely. As with the original Shield version, the virtual desktop is also streamed from Nvidia servers. An Android client was also introduced in 2019.

How can somebody disallow their games from this platform, when all geforce now is actually doing, is streaming the games you **already own** from **another digital platform** like steam, to your device?

If there was a lawsuit for this, would there be any chance for geforce to actually lose?

Now I obviously don't know the laws, but how can a game publisher stop me, for example, from using a virtual machine in the cloud to download steam (the games platform), log in with my credentials, download the games that I already own on steam and stream the gameplay to my device at home?
Is there any law or agreement that would make any of this illegal?

And if there isn't, wouldn't it mean that there shouldn't be any legal issue for a third party to basically automate the above process for you? Because that's basically what geforce now is doing.

Answer (score 4):

### You don't *own* those games

**You have a licence to use them in accordance with the terms you agreed**

> The Content and Services are licensed, not sold. Your license confers no title or ownership in the Content and Services.

One of those [terms](https://store.steampowered.com/subscriber_agreement/) (2G) includes:

> but you are not entitled to: ...  (ii) host or provide matchmaking services for the Content and Services or emulate or redirect the communication protocols used by Valve in any network feature of the Content and Services, through protocol emulation, tunneling, modifying or adding components to the Content and Services, use of a utility program or any other techniques now known or hereafter developed, for any purpose including, but not limited to network play over the Internet, network play utilizing commercial or non-commercial gaming networks or as part of content aggregation networks, websites or services, without the prior written consent of Valve;

So, did you get Valve's prior written consent?

Comment: But since geforce now works with the majority of your titles on steam, I'm guessing nvidia has their consent, wouldn't they? How would the publishers of the games on steam be able to opt out of this, if it's a license that nvidia would agree with steam, and not the game publishers?

Comment: @Mesos Steam may not have the ability to blanket license all games distributed through it for Geforce Now - they will know which ones are and are not licensed.

Comment: While this might be part of their terms and services, it's not really a good fit; it's specifically referring to multiplayer components.  In particular, single-player games will not make use of these components, and a multi-player game hosted through GeForce Now would use them "normally".